# Is there a way of getting a cleaner JSON out of Couchdb?

Tags: json, couchdb

I am wondering if there is a way to get a cleaner JSON with just the docs out of Couchdb instead of getting it under "rows" and then "doc"

This is the default output

```
    {
   "total_rows":1,
   "offset":0,
   "rows":[
      {
         "id":"7d9fd5824f9029186c1eec1bda005e75",
         "key":"7d9fd5824f9029186c1eec1bda005e75",
         "value":{
            "rev":"1-f99879f67cfd27685f92c884c236a0fd"
         },
         "doc":{
            "_id":"7d9fd5824f9029186c1eec1bda005e75",
            "_rev":"1-f99879f67cfd27685f92c884c236a0fd",
            "title":"Hello World",
            "messeges":"This is the first messege. Helloo there"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This is the desired output:

```
    {
   "_id":"7d9fd5824f9029186c1eec1bda005e75",
   "_rev":"1-f99879f67cfd27685f92c884c236a0fd",
   "title":"Hello World",
   "messeges":"This is the first messege. Helloo there"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you querying couchDB?  Your desired output looks exactly like the result of a standard document GET.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't explain more, I meant to get all the docs in more clean way instead of the 'head' with the rows information.

Comment: No, there's not a cleaner way to get all docs. But it should be pretty easy/trivial to loop through the results to get the docs you need.

Comment: I did find a way using node js . Thanks for your time

Comment: Yeah, your solution is exactly what I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help. 
I figured out a way doing it in Node js by using a map function attached to there query

in the nano page they listed it as

```
alice.list().then((body) => {
  body.rows.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc);
  });
});
```

instead I used it like this

```
alice.list().then((body) => {
  var result = body.rows.map( (x) => {
      return x.doc
  });
   console.log(result);
});
```

which works for me.

Still new till couchdb and databases in general.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to see your code. I suspect this is the output of the [alldocs api](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-all-docs)? If you know the ID of the document you want you can use the [get api](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/document/common.html) which returns the JSON you want. Otherwise you must loop through the "rows" ie

```
for (x in results.rows) {...}
```

and then use x.doc to get your JSON.